# MySQLi Insert or Update

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update, sql-insert

i am coding a custom loading Screen for my Half-Life Gameserver.
I want to display the last Visit, the Map and the Steam Name.
Everything works quite well but my last Visit Insert does not work.
It worked before and i didn't even changed anything.

```
include('mysql.php');

$map = $_GET['map'];
$communityid = $_GET['steamid'];
$apikey = "***SECRETAPIKEY***";

if(!empty($map) && !empty($communityid)) {

    if(empty($map)) { $map = "undefined"; }

    $authserver = bcsub( $communityid, '76561197960265728' ) & 1;
    $authid = ( bcsub( $communityid, '76561197960265728' ) - $authserver ) / 2;

    $steamid = "STEAM_0:$authserver:$authid";

    // Load Player data
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key='.$apikey.'&steamids='.$communityid.'&format=xml');
    $name = $xml->players->player->personaname;
    $avatar = $xml->players->player->avatarfull;

    // Fetch Last online from User
    $lastonline_get = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM lastonline WHERE steamid = '".$steamid."'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($lastonline_get))
    {
      $user_lastonline = $row->lastonline;
    }

    // Count from last connect
    function diff_time($differenz)
    {
        $differenz = time() - $differenz;
        $tag  = floor($differenz / (3600*24)); 
        $std  = floor($differenz / 3600 % 24); 
        $min  = floor($differenz / 60 % 60); 
        $sek  = floor($differenz % 60); 

        return array("sek"=>$sek,"min"=>$min,"std"=>$std,"tag"=>$tag,"woche"=>$woche); 
    }

    $difftime_lastonline = diff_time($user_lastonline);

    if($difftime_lastonline['tag']!=0) { $user_whenlastonline = $difftime_lastonline['tag']." Tage ".$difftime_lastonline['std']." Stunden und ".$difftime_lastonline['min']." Minuten "; }
    elseif($difftime_lastonline['std']!=0) { $user_whenlastonline = $difftime_lastonline['std']." Stunden und ".$difftime_lastonline['min']." Minuten "; }
    else { $user_whenlastonline = $difftime_lastonline['min']." Minuten "; }

    // Last online Updaten

    if(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM lastonline WHERE steamid = '".$steamid."'")) {
        $lastonline_updaten = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE lastonline Set lastonline = '".time()."' WHERE steamid = '".$steamid."'");
    } else {
        $lastonline_eintragen = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO lastonline (steamid, lastonline) VALUES ('".$steamid."', '".time()."')");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I try to check, if there is an already existing database entry for the steamid. If it is not, it should create one. If it is, it should update the existing one.

But when i run the code, it does not insert anything. (I checked the URL etc.)

**Why do you use GET?**
Those Variables (Map & SteamID64Bit) only works within the URL..

Comment: If you define steamid as being unique in your MySQL table you could avoid the if-statement at the end alltogether and simply use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. See [section 13.2.5.3. of the MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to sigy i got it to work now.
Instead of

```
// Last online Updaten

if(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM lastonline WHERE steamid = '".$steamid."'")) {
    $lastonline_updaten = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE lastonline Set lastonline = '".time()."' WHERE steamid = '".$steamid."'");
} else {
    $lastonline_eintragen = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO lastonline (steamid, lastonline) VALUES ('".$steamid."', '".time()."')");
}
```

I changed the field 'steamid' to UNIQUE in phpmyadmin and changed this section to

```
    // Last online Updaten
    $lastonline_eintragen = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO lastonline (steamid, lastonline) VALUES ('".$steamid."', '".time()."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastonline='".time()."'");
```

Comment: If this solved your problem then you should mark your own post as answer.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is you are checking `if(!empty($map) && !empty($communityid))` inside that you have `if(empty($map)`. If $map is empty or is not empty the second if statement will never execute. This would work,

```
$communityid = $_GET['steamid'];
$apikey = "***SECRETAPIKEY***";

if(empty($_GET['map']))
{ 

    $map = 'undefined map'

}
else if (!empty($_GET['map']) && !empty($communityid)
{

    $map = $_GET['map'];

    $authserver = bcsub( $communityid, '76561197960265728' ) & 1;
    $authid = ( bcsub( $communityid, '76561197960265728' ) - $authserver ) / 2;

    $steamid = "STEAM_0:$authserver:$authid";
```

Comment: I changed if(!empty($map) && !empty($communityid)) { to if(!empty($communityid)) { and left if(empty($map)) { $map = "undefined"; } in the script.. thank you :)